# disable select no cakephp

Tags: cakephp, select

Tenho 2 selects, e quero fazer com que quando um dos select estiver com uma opção diferente de vazio, o outro select entre em disable.

Segue meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function handleSelect() {
 if (this.value == '30') {
     document.getElementById('agente_id').disabled = true;
 } else {
     document.getElementById('agente_id').disabled = false;
 }
 }
  </script>
  <div class='container'>
<form method="get" action="/financeiro/gerar_relatorios">
<div class='panel panel-primary'>        
    <div class='panel-heading'><B>FILTRAR COMISSÕES POR PERÍODO</b></div>        
    <div class='panel-body'>       
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                <?= $this->Form->input('data_inicio', array('class' => 'form-control mask_date','value'=> @$_GET['data']['data_inicio'])); ?>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                <?= $this->Form->input('data_fim', array('class' => 'form-control mask_date','value'=> @$_GET['data']['data_fim'])); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                 <?= $this->Form->input('colaborador_id', array('class' => 'form-control','empty'=>'Filtrar todos colaboradores','value'=> @$_GET['data']['colaborador_id'])); ?>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                 <?= $this->Form->input('agente_id', array('class' => 'form-control','empty'=>'Filtrar todos agentes','value'=> @$_GET['data']['agente_id'])); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                 <?= $this->Form->input('compra', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Filtre pelo número da compra','value'=> @$_GET['data']['compra'])); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div class='panel-footer'>
        <?= $this->Form->submit('Filtrar', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')); ?>
    </div>        
</div>
</form>
```

A minha dúvida é, como instanciar essa função js no select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('compra', 
                    array('class' => 'form-control',
                          'placeholder' => 'Filtre pelo número da compra',
                          'value' => @$_GET['data']['compra'], 
                          'onchange' => "handleSelect(this);")
                   ); ?>
```

Comment: Fiz desta maneira, mas quando seleciono a opção que o value é 30, o select `agente_id`, continua habilitado.

Comment: ok, mas ele está entrando na função do handleSelect ? caso esteja veja o que vem no this.value e poste aqui

Comment: estou tentando debugar no fireBug, mas no console não mostra nada.

Comment: coloque um console.log dentro da função antes da condição

Comment: desta maneira? 
`        function handleSelect() {
          console.log(this);
          if (this.value == '30') {
          document.getElementById('agente_id').disabled = true;
     }
 }`

Comment: @MichelHenriq isso, só pra ver se está ta entrando na função, se estiver entrando e me dê o retorno

Comment: No console não aparece nada, e eu deixei o outro select disabled, e eu seleciono a opção que tem o value 30, e o select não sai do disabled..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29671/discussion-between-thiago-friedman-and-michel-henriq).